# javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for JMeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am using Apache Jmeter as a Proxy to record a script on a website that requires login.

When I validate the script after the recording. I am getting this error in the JMeter log.

```
    2020-06-17 12:57:48,760 WARN o.a.j.p.h.c.KerberosManager: Could not log in user ${AUTH_LOGIN}
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for JMeter
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:417) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.KerberosManager.lambda$getSubjectForUser$0(KerberosManager.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.KerberosManager.getSubjectForUser(KerberosManager.java:82) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager.getSubjectForUrl(AuthManager.java:298) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:918) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:641) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1281) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1270) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

****I have defined AUTH_LOGIN & AUTH_PASSWORD in USER_DEFINED_Variable****

I will highly appreciate your help as I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just record the .jmx script - it might be easier to go for [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Going forward if you will be load testing this application you will face this issue again, it means that your application is using [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) protocol for authenticating users so you will need to:

1. Add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and:

   - provide your credentials
   - provide your domain and realm
   - choose `Kerberos` as the "Mechanism"
2. Provide necessary configuration in *jaas.conf* and *krb5.conf* files (both live under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more detailed information and example configuration.

You might also be interested in [Java Authentication and Authorization Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/java-authentication-and-authorization-service-jaas1.htm) documentation